# Merge two datasets based on time interval in R

Tags: r, merge

I have two datasets.

Dataset **X** looks as follows. It contains 30-min intervals of the trading day of some stock index, which opens 9:30AM and closes at 15:00PM for DJ, but 16:00PM for DX. So the closing time may vary by Ticker.

```
 Date    Ticker end_time start_time
1997-10-06  DJ  10:00   09:30
1997-10-06  DJ  10:30   10:00
1997-10-06  DJ  11:00   10:30
1997-10-06  DJ  11:30   11:00
1997-10-08  DJ  09:30   15:00
1997-10-08  DJ  10:00   09:30
1997-10-06  DX  10:00   09:30
1997-10-06  DX  10:30   10:00
1997-10-06  DX  11:00   10:30
1997-10-06  DX  11:30   11:00
1997-10-07  DX  14:30   14:00
1997-10-07  DX  15:00   14:30
1997-10-07  DX  15:30   15:00
1997-10-07  DX  16:00   15:30
1997-10-08  DX  09:30   16:00
1997-10-08  DX  10:00   09:30
```

Dataset **Y** looks as follows:

```
Date Time Event
1997-10-06  09:30   Event1
1997-10-06  10:30   Event2
1997-10-07  22:00   Event3
1997-10-08  09:00   Event4
1997-10-08  09:30   Event5
1997-10-08  09:30   Event6
```

My aim is to link events in **Y** to **X** based on whether the event date-time occurs within the start/end time interval. My expected output is something (data-set **Z**):

```
Date    Ticker end_time start_time Event
1997-10-06  DJ  10:00   09:30 Event1
1997-10-06  DJ  10:30   10:00 NA
1997-10-06  DJ  11:00   10:30 Event2
1997-10-06  DJ  11:30   11:00 NA
1997-10-08  DJ  09:30   15:00 Event3,Event4
1997-10-08  DJ  10:00   09:30 Event5,Event6
1997-10-06  DX  10:00   09:30 Event1
1997-10-06  DX  10:30   10:00 NA
1997-10-06  DX  11:00   10:30 Event2
1997-10-06  DX  11:30   11:00 NA
1997-10-07  DX  14:30   14:00 NA
1997-10-07  DX  15:00   14:30 NA
1997-10-07  DX  15:30   15:00 NA
1997-10-07  DX  16:00   15:30 NA
1997-10-08  DX  09:30   16:00 Event3, Event4
1997-10-08  DX  10:00   09:30 Event5,Event6
```

It is thus possible to multiple events happen between an interval. Is it possible to store those in column "Event". It is also possible that Event occurs after a market closes, which should be stored in the first interval that occurs after the event. How can I obtain this expected output? I have been thinking for a while now, but I have no clue where to start.

Edit: X contains 400k 30-min intervals. Y contains 40k events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of ways of approaching the problem, here's just one suggestion.

I'm using these datasets:

```
x <- read.table(text = "Date,Ticker,end_time,start_time
06/10/1997,DJ,10:00,09:30
06/10/1997,DJ,10:30,10:00
06/10/1997,DJ,11:00,10:30
06/10/1997,DJ,11:30,11:00
08/10/1997,DJ,09:30,15:00
08/10/1997,DJ,10:00,09:30
06/10/1997,DX,10:00,09:30
06/10/1997,DX,10:30,10:00
06/10/1997,DX,11:00,10:30
06/10/1997,DX,11:30,11:00
07/10/1997,DX,14:30,14:00
07/10/1997,DX,15:00,14:30
07/10/1997,DX,15:30,15:00
07/10/1997,DX,16:00,15:30
08/10/1997,DX,09:30,16:00
08/10/1997,DX,10:00,09:30
08/10/1997,DX,10:00,09:30", sep =",", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors =         
  FALSE)

y <- read.table(text = "Date,Time,Event
06/10/1997,09:30,Event1
06/10/1997,10:30,Event2
07/10/1997,22:00,Event3
08/10/1997,09:00,Event4
08/10/1997,09:30,Event5
08/10/1997,09:30,Event6
", sep =",", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I would start by concatenating and formatting the dates and times so they can be used in functions to check whether an event occurred in that window. Assuming you have two data frames called x and y in the structure described above:

```
y$date_time <- strptime(paste(y$Time,y$Date),format="%H:%M %d/%m/%Y")
x$start_time_date <- strptime(paste(x$start_time,x$Date),format="%H:%M %d/%m/%Y")
x$end_time_date <- strptime(paste(x$end_time,x$Date),format="%H:%M %d/%m/%Y")
```

If you have control over the dataset as it is compiled then it might be easier for the start and end dates to be recorded in this way, as for the periods that cross over a date doing it this way will produce start date-times that are after the end date-times. We can edit those by just instead using the date from the previous entry in the data frame, assuming it will always be in chronological order and there won't be missing periods. This is a bit of a hack!:

```
#check which entries cross over a date
overnight_idx <- which(x$end_time_date < x$start_time_date)
#replace start date with that of preceding entry in the data frame
x[overnight_idx, 'start_time_date'] <- 
  as.POSIXct(paste(x[overnight_idx, 'start_time'],
                 x[overnight_idx - 1, 'Date']),format="%H:%M %d/%m/%Y", 
            origin = "1970-01-01")
```

Now we can write a function that for a given row in the data frame x will extract any events that have occurred listed in y, and then do a little bit of formatting to get it in the format you described.

```
checkEvent <- function(x_row){
  y2 <- y[y$date_time>=x_row['start_time_date'] &
            y$date_time<x_row['end_time_date'], 'Event']
  if(length(y2)==0){
    y2 <- NA
  }  else if(length(y2)>1){
    y2 <- paste(y2,collapse = ' ')
  }
  return(y2)
}
```

Then we can just apply that to x

```
x$Event <- apply(x,1,checkEvent)
```

which will produce the following (ignoring the columns we created above so it fits on the screen):

```
> x[,c('Date','Ticker','end_time','start_time','Event')]
         Date Ticker end_time start_time         Event
1  06/10/1997     DJ    10:00      09:30        Event1
2  06/10/1997     DJ    10:30      10:00          <NA>
3  06/10/1997     DJ    11:00      10:30        Event2
4  06/10/1997     DJ    11:30      11:00          <NA>
5  08/10/1997     DJ    09:30      15:00 Event3 Event4
6  08/10/1997     DJ    10:00      09:30 Event5 Event6
7  06/10/1997     DX    10:00      09:30        Event1
8  06/10/1997     DX    10:30      10:00          <NA>
9  06/10/1997     DX    11:00      10:30        Event2
10 06/10/1997     DX    11:30      11:00          <NA>
11 07/10/1997     DX    14:30      14:00          <NA>
12 07/10/1997     DX    15:00      14:30          <NA>
13 07/10/1997     DX    15:30      15:00          <NA>
14 07/10/1997     DX    16:00      15:30          <NA>
15 08/10/1997     DX    09:30      16:00 Event3 Event4
16 08/10/1997     DX    10:00      09:30 Event5 Event6
17 08/10/1997     DX    10:00      09:30 Event5 Event6
```

Comment: Hi Sam, in the last column I obtain a list. So for the first row <df[,1] [1 x 1]> rather than Event1 and in the second row I obtain <df[,1] [0 x 1]> instead of NA. Do you know how I can solve that?

Comment: I guess your data frame isn't structured properly - I've edited the answer to provide useable data frames with the same data